Is there a way to grant Visual Studio Code Sudo priviledges?
I'm on Fedora 40. I have Apache, MySql and PHP installed. I'm editing files in the Apache server host folders, so I can use localhost to see the edits. The permissions are pretty strict. I now have to enter my root password every time I save my files. Something which is getting old pretty quick.
Is there not some way to give Visual Studio Code root privileges? I'm just working on pet projects. Even if it is a security risk there is no real sensitive information on this PC.

Why not give yourself permissions to edit those files instead of giving VSCode root privileges.

make sure it's owned by root and set the suid bit,
chown -v root:root /usr/bin/code;
chmod -v u+s /usr/bin/code;

Note: I haven't actually tested this myself, but in theory it should work..

Thank You, I had to go search for it with the which code command because I installed it with a snap in a different directory

Hmm... allowing MS root access? I-wouldn't-wanna-do-that... ;-)

Yeah, I have to agree with Hannu. Not only because it's MS, but because most of the modules are 3rd party. And if your developing with an opensource language or environment, your going to have all sorts of modular code executing. It just isn't safe, especially if you access social media accounts, trade crypto, pay bills, order door dash or do banking on the computer your using VS Code with. Not to sound like Fox Mulder, but "trust no one".
